# Instruction trace using frida in android emulator

Tags: debugging, x86, android, arm, frida

i have a emulator named "Ldplayer" in my windows os and I'm trying to log all instructions executed by the app that uses ARM JNI libraries. basically, the app is running in an x86 emulator and only has arm JNI Libs, so emulation is used for the ARM Libs.

```
import frida, sys
ss = """
Java.perform(function() {
    const System = Java.use('java.lang.System');
    const Runtime = Java.use('java.lang.Runtime');
    const VMStack = Java.use('dalvik.system.VMStack');

    System.loadLibrary.implementation = function(library) {
        try {
            console.log('System.loadLibrary("' + library + '")');
            const loaded = Runtime.getRuntime().loadLibrary0(VMStack.getCallingClassLoader(), library);
            return loaded;
        } catch(ex) {
            console.log(ex);
        }
    };
    
    System.load.implementation = function(library) {
        try {
            console.log('System.load("' + library + '")');
            const loaded = Runtime.getRuntime().load0(VMStack.getCallingClassLoader(), library);
            return loaded;
        } catch(ex) {
            console.log(ex);
        }
    };
});
"""
device = frida.get_device_manager().add_remote_device('127.0.0.1:27042')
pid = device.spawn(["com.testapp"])
session = device.attach(pid)
script = session.create_script(ss)
script.load()
device.resume(pid)
sys.stdin.read()
```

this code list all libraries loaded when the app starts, but when i do

`Module.findBaseAddress('libtest.so');`

it always returns null, in the end of the day i just want to log all the instructions being executed by the process so i can get the faulty instruction and search it up in the ida to patch it.
if there's any other tool i can achieve the same than please suggest me also, process don't support attaching a debugger!

Comment: Usually module names don't end with `.so`. I would try `libtest` or `test` as module name.

Comment: hi, the frida dev told that it doesn't seeks for emulated process

Comment: can u suggest me some other tool with which i can get logs of all the instructions executed by the process until it crashes finally ? i cant attach a debugger but i can hook

Comment: Why not simply using a rooted Android device?

Comment: its rooted by default

Comment: im looking to do this in emulator that's why i raised this question )

Comment: Ultimately, your easiest solution would be to seek out the APK which would directly support x86 OR use a non-x86 based emulator.

Though ultimately, I think you're not explaining what you actually want;
 "so i can get the faulty instruction "

Is the faulty instruction happening on a /real/ device or the emulator? If a real device, you likely should inject a frida gadget (root not required) and work there. Otherwise you'll lose the fidelity of what actual ARM instructions are being run. If on an emulator, compile a debug version of the translation layer.

Comment: i tried injecting frida gadget (arm) in an x86 emulator in apps one of the jni libs and replaced that lib in /data/data/com.myapp and started the app but frida server crashed note that i added it as the dependency in the app's own native libs, i injected a arm 32 lib in arm32 lib as a dependency

Comment: F Frida   : frida-core/lib/gadget/gadget.vala:679:frida_gadget_detect_location: assertion failed: (our_range != null)

Comment: A problem with doing things on emulators, is that, some actions might not be supported, as you have found.

Comment: yeah ik look at https://github.com/nevermoe/ehook, can u tell me how can i log instructions in real time with this ?